# Does a 1 kHz signal have harmonics above or below 1 kHz, and where is its fundamental frequency?

Tags: frequency, signal-processing

I'm having an argument with a friend ─ he believes a 1 kHz audio signal has its fundamental frequency at 1 kHz with harmonics above that value, while I believe the fundamental frequency will be far below 1 kHz with harmonics occurring between that value and 1 kHz.

Which of us is right?

Comment: What do you mean by a "1 kHz audio signal"? Do you mean a sine wave at 1 kHz?

Comment: We were using an oscillator to generate a signal at 1Khz. I'm unfortunately not sure how to answer the question beyond that. I think that's a 1Khz sine wave, right?

Comment: For an ideal oscillator, yes, it would be a sine wave at 1 kHz. In that case, the spectrum of such a signal is a Dirac delta function at 1 kHz.

Comment: So....does that mean....there is no fundamental frequency...?

Comment: The fundamental frequency is at 1 kHz,  but since the signal is a sine wave, in an ideal oscillator there would be no harmonics above or below that value.

Comment: "A 1 kHz signal" is very vague and I could think of at least 4 different things that could possibly mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure sine wave contains only its fundamental frequency, which in your case is 1kHz. It contains no harmonics.

Answer (score 4):

Basically **your friend is right**.

The usual understanding of "a 1 kHz signal" is that you're dealing with a pure sine wave at that frequency, which has its fundamental frequency at 1 kHz and no harmonics at all. However, it is reasonable to speak, say, about a sawtooth waveform at 1 kHz ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2CPkGkDMgw)), in which case 1 kHz represents the repetition period of the waveform, and the spectrum will consist of a fundamental at 1 kHz and harmonics at multiples of that frequency.

The only way to map your understanding to language that is correctly used is to speak of

> a signal whose support includes 1 kHz,

in which case you could indeed have a lower fundamental frequency, but that is in no way implied by the phrasing you used.

Answer (score 0):

In general, sounds that you would interpret as sounding like the same note as a 1 kHz pure tone (that is about two octaves above middle C), have their fundamental frequency at 1 kHz and harmonics above that.